# 28 pin SMD part marked AQ7DL identification

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, pc

Can anyone help me identify this part?
It is in my Dell AIO PC. It's located beside the power inlet. I guess it's some kind of power controller chip.

[image]

P/N of MB is 0F65P3

It was burnt after a few power cycle.

[image: close up shot]

[image: Best before I could get from internet]

Comment: wow, that's a toasted little IC. The width of the traces suggests this is some power management electronics. So, make sure that there's not something else that caused this IC to blow! Looking at the massive damage, I'd assume that there was a massive overcurrent condition, and it's really not clear what else on that board is damaged. Have you done fault reason analysis? You might need to replace the whole board.

Comment: 1) I don't recognise [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYSFC.png) part of the Manufacturer logo. Are you able to provide a better quality of this part?
2) And is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3cz5.png) a mere reflection, or could it be something of value?

Comment: It would be easier if you also post a photo of the area around it too, and the AIO model number

Comment: Please see more information above.

Comment: From schematic its APA2619RI.